# dayjs() telling me invalid date for this date string

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, date, dayjs

[DayJs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs)

Using it on the browser if that matters (firefox + Vue + typescript).

This is my date string

> 2021-02-05 12:00 AM

It fusses about the AM/PM in my code:

```
const dateObj: any = dayjs('2021-02-05 12:00 AM').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A');
```

The output of `dateObj` is always "Invalid Date". If I remove the "AM" from the string it parses correctly. If I try [this](https://jstool.gitlab.io/dayjs/) online tester for the same code, the output is

> NaN-NaN-NaN NaN:NaN PM

Like with my dev environment, if I remove the AM, it's fine.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Working on Chrome and not Firefox...

Comment: I get `2021-02-05 12:00 AM` in the tester you linked. I used `dayjs('2021-02-05 12:00 AM').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A')`.

Comment: @Ouroborus Weird, here's a screenshot of my result: https://i.imgur.com/WrtSk9Z.png
EDIT: Seems to be working on Chrome and not FF???

Answer (score 33):

#### Issue on Firefox

If you deeply look at the implementation, you would see above day string going through the `Day` constructor: `new Day('2021-02-05 12:00 AM')`. Unfortunately FF doesn't support this support this day string format, but Chrome does.

#### Best approach

The [dayjs documentation](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string) mentions:

> For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use String + Format.

If you're still keen to use above format, you would have to use a plugin as mentioned [here](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/custom-parse-format)

Basically, you have to change as below to work in all browsers:

```js
import customParseFormat from 'dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat'
import dayjs from "dayjs"

dayjs.extend(customParseFormat)

const yourDate = dayjs('2021-02-05 12:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A')
```

Comment: This should be the default. Very misleading considering that the dayjs website's console extends this plugin. Great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a plugin:

```
  import dayjs from 'dayjs'
  import customParseFormat from 'dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat'
  
  dayjs.extend(customParseFormat)
```

Then it should work:

https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/custom-parse-format